.NET Core 9 : tracking model changes and reporting back to UI?
I'm a little confused on how to use ChangeTracker in .NET Core 9 and report back to the UI that a user has modified bound model properties?
UPDATED:
Use case.

Model is instantiated from dbContext query via Entities (LINQ).
Controls are bound to the Model properties.
User makes a change to Model's bound property via UI TextBox.
As soon as the model receives the new value, update UI text area with "unsaved changes".
User clicks on Save button, data is saved to DB and "unsaved changes" is cleared form UI text area.

Yes .NET 9 EF/Core ChangeTracker ... which requires the original "context" for when the data is retrieved (via entity ref) and then assigned to a model.
With .NET 9 and Blazor-Server, one operates via injection of a service (with it's interface) and context is established in the service methods which is typically called from the page/UI to bind models to controls.
As per article from Microsoft here, the context is normally disposed after queried.  So how can ChangeTrack work on UI side/code without context when wanting to relay it's state to the UI?
Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?  I can accomplish this via other methods using events (OnUpdate for the controls).  I was expecting Tracking to be accessible via checking the model state, but that doesn't seem to be the case, only via context.

What are you confused about? Your question is very general. What is your use case?

Are you talking about the Change Tracker in Entity Framework Core 9 ?

Updated my question with more detail.

I'm going to delete this question, as more research into ChangeTracker and it will NOT  efficiently (key being efficiently) accomplish my objectives.  I would still need to either use model get/set (which doesn't really work if user changes values back to original) OR reload entity and map to model and check entity state ... and this would need to happen on every property set and/or retain entity (not dispose) for compare to model.  All pretty ugly and memory consuming.
